# Интервал от начала недели PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL. Имеется следующее условие:

```
WHERE datedecision BETWEEN date_trunc('day', CAST(${dateFrom} as timestamp)) AND date_trunc('day',CAST(${dateFrom} as timestamp) + INTERVAL '1 day') )
```

`${dateFrom}` - выбираемая пользователем дата во внешней системе.

На данный момент это позволяет фильтровать значения за один выбранный день (например, с 26.04.2021 00:00:00 по 27.04.2021 00:00:00).

Необходимо изменить условие так, чтобы значения фильтровались от понедельника предшествущего выбранной дате по выбранную дату. (Например, ${dateFrom} = 15.04.2021, тогда фильтрация должна быть с 12.04.2021  по 15.04.2021 включительно). Возможно ли такое реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: так определите какой день недели указанная дата, и отнимите столько от нее, получите начало недели.

Comment: Пробовал сделать  ${dateFrom - INTERVAL (EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM TIMESTAMP ${dateFrom} )), ругался что INTERVAL не поддерживает работу с такими аргументами

Comment: так заведите еще одну переменную, сначала в ней посчитайте, а потом обе подставьте в запросы.

Comment: После `date_trunc` надо ещё отнять `interval 'x day'`, где `x` - номер дня недели введённой даты, считая `понедельник = 0`.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, переменных нет в PostgreSQL, а в WITH определяется столбец. Из TIMESTAMP невозможно вычесть столбец. Или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 2):

CTE? Зачем? На старых версиях postgresql только планировщик путать будете. [Простого `date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) достаточно:

```
    datedecision >= date_trunc('week', timestamp '2021-04-15') 
and datedecision < timestamp '2021-04-15' + interval '1 day'
```

---

Обратите внимание, что between подразумевает `<=` в условии, т.е. `2021-04-16 00:00:00.000` входит в интервал. Обычно в подобных задачах подразумевается такие даты уже не включать в фильтр.

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашлось:

```
WITH chdate AS
    (SELECT EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM TIMESTAMP ${dateFrom})::INT AS ddays)
```

Затем используем полученное значение

```
WHERE datedecision BETWEEN date_trunc('day', CAST(${dateFrom} as timestamp) - ddays + 1) AND date_trunc('day',CAST(${dateFrom} as timestamp))
```